# ANT: set property using loadfile if certain multi-line pattern is found

Tags: regex, ant

I have a source code file which contains, among others, following lines:

```
   public boolean isBetaVersion() {
      return true;
   }
```

I try to read this file in ANT and set a property depending on whether the above method returns `true` or something else:

```
<loadfile srcfile="path/to/MyFile.java" property="isBetaBuild">
   <filterchain>
      <striplinebreaks/>
      <linecontainsregexp>
          <regexp pattern=".*\sisBetaVersion()\s\{\sreturn\strue.*"/>
      </linecontainsregexp>
   </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

but it never matches (unfortunately, I'm a complete regex-noob). Anyone has an idea what could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses, and allow for more than just one whitespace character. Then, `\b` anchors can be used to match beginnings and ends of words, which is also helpful here. I suggest you try this:

```
<regexp pattern="\bisBetaVersion\(\)\s+\{\s+return\s+true\b"/>
```

You don't need the `.*` around the regex, since you're just looking for whether that substring is contained in the source code somewhere.